# Trouble with VLC after installing Makemkv

Tags: 14.04, vlc

I am relatively new to Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm having some trouble.

I had VLC installed on my computer without problems. About a week ago I tried to install Makemkv to get the Bluray codecs on my computer to play Blurays from an external CD/DVD drive. However, VLC will not recognize the DVD I insert into my CD/DVD ROM drive although it makes noises when doing so.

So now I can't watch any DVD

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) You're talking about an external CD/DVD drive.  What is the brand and type?  And what is the output to `lsusb` (if hooked up through USB).

Answer (score 0):

open VLC player and right click on it, in the drop down box select open media then select open disc then in the disc selection menu choose blu-ray by clicking on the button then select the correct path to external dvd  in the DISC Device then play that disc.

Comment: @Jamie most of the time when you choose Blu-ray it will automatically pick the default path of disc but since you are playing from external DVD drive u might have to choose path in the Disc device